# Putting string read from file inside double quote

Tags: bash

I am reading from an input file that contains few hexadecimal numbers from a bash script. Then, I want to pass those strings as command line argument of an executable file.

Say, here is my `test.txt`:

```
278dca53f96014be
6c39b2d481e75f0a
38e5942f6bd0c71a
```

I am reading it through the script:

```
i=0
while read line || [ "$line" ]; do
    arr[$i]="$line"
    i=$((i+1))
done < test.txt

max=2
for n in `seq 0 $max`
do
s=${arr[$n]}
./main -o $s
done
```

As you can see, the numbers are passed as command line option for `./main`.

Now, the problem is, I need to keep `$s` within double quotes. I tried this:

```
$t='"'
$s=$t$s$t
```

but it did not work.

Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need to double quote `$s` as you should always do with variables?

Comment: Just use `"$s"`? Or du you actually need the double quotes to be part of the argument?

Comment: ...and `s="${arr[$n]}"`. Or omit the `$s` entirely and do `./main -o "${arr[$n]}"`

Comment: Adding double quotes around $s did not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid bug report.

Comment: Actually, I got an invalid output from the program `main`. It is consistent with length of the argument being less than expected (expected is 16).

Comment: Each line in your input file is 16 characters long...

Comment: I meant, if you pass less than 16 numbers as argument of `main`, then it produces an invalid output. The outputs I got by encasing `$s` by double quotes are consistent with this case.

Comment: I think I have a clue. `\r` is probably causing the problem for the end `"`.

Answer (score 2):

From comments, it sounds as if your `test.txt` file comes from a Windows system and is a DOS text file.  You should convert it to a Unix text file with `dos2unix`.  Alternatively, modify the below to use `tr -d '\r' <test.txt | head -n 3` in place of just `head -n 3 test.txt`.

---

You have a file with lines of text, and you need to invoke the script/program `main` once each for the three first of these lines:

```
head -n 3 test.txt | xargs -n 1 main -o
```

If you *really* need the double quotes to be part of the argument (this is unusual):

```
head -n 3 test.txt | xargs -I XX main -o '"XX"'
```

To invoke `main` once for *each* line in the file, use

```
xargs -n 1 main -o <test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *GNU* `sed`'s `e`*valuate* command:

```
sed 's#^#./main -o &#e' test.txt
```

And if the formatting is wrong, just precede that with some code. 
For example, if the format for the first line should be "*./main -o 27 8d ca 53 f9 60 14 be*", this would work:

```
sed 's/../& /g;s#^#./main -o &#e' test.txt
```